# Groupby with a condition on another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where I am doing the following :

```
df1 = df.groupby('Date_1')['weight'].sum().reset_index(name='total_weight')
```

I am trying to aggregate the total sum of weights for a particular date.

I want to add a condition such that it takes sum only when is_b is 1. is_b is another column where there are 2 values 0 and 1.

Can anyone advise as to how to use the condition with groupby in pandas.

Thanks

**EDIT**

DF

```
Date_1    weight isBooked
01/09/2019  181  1
01/09/2019  189  1
01/09/2019  174  1
01/09/2019  267  1
01/09/2019  308  1
02/09/2019  79   0
02/09/2019  179  1
02/09/2019  435  1
```

Note that dataframe has other columns as well, just posting the relevant fields here.

Comment: Can you post some sample data in text format so that we can check and expected output.

Comment: @nitin3685 I have added the example dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check whether this is what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
csv = StringIO('''Date_1    weight isBooked
        01/09/2019  181  1
        01/09/2019  189  1
        01/09/2019  174  1
        01/09/2019  267  1
        01/09/2019  308  1
        02/09/2019  79   0
        02/09/2019  179  1
        02/09/2019  435  1''')
df = pd.read_csv(csv, delim_whitespace=True)
df1 = df.loc[df.isBooked == 1 ].groupby('Date_1')['weight'].sum().reset_index(name='total_weight')
print(df1)
```

Output is

```
       Date_1  total_weight
0  01/09/2019          1119
1  02/09/2019           614
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` on the result of the multiplication:

```
(df['weight'] * df['isBooked']).groupby(df['Date_1']).sum()
```

Output:

```
Date_1
01/09/2019    1119
02/09/2019     614
dtype: int64
```